# How to proof that every group $G$ with closure operator $C(X) =<X>$ (generator of G for every $X \subseteq G$) is algebraic lattice?

Tags: lattice-orders

I have to proof what's in question. I know that $C(X) = \langle X \rangle $ is algebraic closure operator in $G$ and have draft of this proof in my head, but still don't get it 100%.

We have to use the defition of algebraic lattice as it is lattice which is complete and compactly generated. I know that only finetly generated subgroups are compact elements of lattice of closed subsets. See it, but can't write it down in proper way.

Could you help me with that or propose me literature which may help me with this proof?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: You define $C(\color{red}X)$ without reference to $X$?

Comment: X is subset of G, as it was said in question.

Comment: But the right hand side "$=\langle G\rangle$" does not depend on $X$, so $C$ is constant?

Comment: So sorry, I made mistake in writing a question and didn't catch it. Thank you for comment. It have to be "$ = \langle X \rangle$" of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $G$ be a group and $L$ the set of all subgroups of $G$.
Then $L$ is partially ordered by $\subseteq$.

In fact, $L$ is a *lattice:* For $A,B\in L$, $A\vee B:=\bigcap\{\,H\in L\mid A,B\subseteq H\,\}$ is a least upper bound and $A\wedge B:=A\cap B$ a greatest lower bound.

In fact, this extends to arbitrary families, i.e., if $A_i\in L$ for $i\in I$, then $$\bigvee_{i\in I}A_i:=\bigcap\{\,H\in L\mid \forall i\in I\colon A_i\subseteq H\,\}$$ is a least upper bound and $$\bigwedge_{i\in I}A_i:=\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i$$ a greatest lower bound for the given family. Thus $L$ is a *complete lattice*.

Note that
$$ \bigcup_{J\subseteq I,\atop|J|<\infty}\bigvee_{j\in J}A_j$$
is a subgroup of $G$ that contains each $A_i$, $i\in I$, i.e., the upper bound of an arbitrary family of lattice elements is in fact the settheoretic union of all upper bounds of all finite subfamilies.

Suppose $A=\langle a_1,\ldots,a_n\rangle \in L$ is finitely generated. Then $A\subseteq \bigvee_{i\in  I}A_i$ implies that each $a_j$ is contained in the upper bound $A_{j,1}\vee\ldots \vee A_{j,n_j}$ over some finite subfamily. It follows that $$A=\bigvee_{j=1}^n\bigvee_{i=1}^{n_j}A_{j,i}.$$  Hence every finitely generated subgroup is a *compact element* of $L$.

For every $A\in L$, we have $A=\bigvee_{a\in A}\langle a\rangle$, and as each $\langle a\rangle$ is finitely generated and hence compact, we conclude that  $L$ is *algebraic.*

Comment: I was thinking, can I change the defition of $\sup_{A_i}$ for $C(\bigcup_{i \in I} A_{i})$ with no consequences?

Comment: @Kasia The one crucial point where one has to invest a *tiny* bit of group theory is when showing that the supremum is in fect the union over suprema of finite subfamilies, i..e, that the $\bigcup\bigvee$ construct is a group. I suppose, you will have use that point one way or other.